# EventFilter for Drop-Events within QTableView

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt5

I try to create a QTableView that can handle drop events. For reasons of application architecture, I want that to be done by an eventFilter of mine (that handles some QAction-triggers for clipboard interaction as well). But the drop-event does not seem to get through to the eventFilter.

I do not care where the data are dropped within the view. That is one of the reasons I want it to be handled by that eventFilter and not by the model. Furthermore, I do not want the model to pop up a dialog ("Are you sure to drop so many elements?"), because user interaction should be done by gui elements.

btw: It **did** actually work in Qt4/PySide.

I set up an example code snippet to illustrate the problem. The interesting thing about this is that there *can* appear QDrop Events, but only in the headers of the item view.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# coding: utf-8

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QTableView,
    QWidget,
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    Qt,
    QStringListModel,
    QEvent
)

app = QApplication([])

window = QMainWindow()

# Table View with Drop-Options
view = QTableView(window)
view.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
view.setDragEnabled(True)
view.setAcceptDrops(True)
view.setDragDropMode(QTableView.DragDrop)
view.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.LinkAction)
view.setDropIndicatorShown(True)

window.setCentralWidget(view)

# Simple Event Filter for TableView
class Filter(QWidget):
    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        print widget, event, event.type()
        if event.type() in (QEvent.DragEnter, QEvent.DragMove, QEvent.Drop):
            print "Drag'n'Drop-Event"
            if event.type() != QEvent.Drop:
                print "\tbut no DropEvent"
                event.acceptProposedAction()
            else:
                print "\tan actual DropEvent"
            return True
        return False
filter = Filter(window)
view.installEventFilter(filter)

class MyModel(QStringListModel):
    # Model with activated DragDrop functionality
    # vor view
    def supportedDragActions(self):
        print "asks supported drop actions"
        return Qt.LinkAction | Qt.CopyAction
    def canDropMimeData(self, *args):
        print "canDropMimeData"
        return True
    def dropMimeData(self, *args):
        print "dropMimeData"
        return True

model = MyModel("Entry_A Entry_B Entry_C".split())
view.setModel(model)

window.show()
window.raise_()
app.exec_()
```

**Final question:** What widget handles the QDropEvents within the QTableView, or what widget should I install the eventFilter on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view.viewport()` gets all the remaining events. So simply **adding**

```
view.viewport().installEventFilter(filter)
```

will do.